# How to interact with HTML page loaded in Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to web development. I am working on an application that will be interacting with the local filesystem. I understand that I need a Node.js server:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

fs.readFile('html1.html', (err, html) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
    });

});
```

I have rendered the html1.html file. Let's say there is a button with id="clickMe" in the html file. Is there a way to have (for example) onlick event for this button, but defined in the Node server file, rather than in the html file?
I read about ways to use Express.js, but is there a way to avoid that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the actual ask? Do you want to add a button from your node to the html file, or you want a button that calls a specific function in your node server.

You can use a templating engine like ejs for the first case.

Comment: Can fuel in a tank in a car dictate to the driver where to turn? The HTML is responsible for working with the buttons. Even if you manipulate the HTML on the serverside - ultimately, it will be placed in HTML.

Comment: Ultimately, html rendered on front-end while the node.js is the back-end server so, if you want to capture the click event on the button which you are rendering through node.js server, you need to attach script to html like as we do in classical way.

Comment: @Mukesh Tivari The problem I have with that is that I will be needing to work with the 'fs' module and using require('fs') throws an exception unless it is called in the node server.